# Ubuntu new software instalation

Tags: jdk

I have to  install jdk in my Ubuntu 17.04v it will display the error like 
unable to locate package default -jdk

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04 is not supported; it reached EOL on 13-Jan-2018 (2017-April + 9 months).  The repos have already been moved to `old-releases.ubuntu.com` which will mean package errors. Upgrade to 17.10 as it should have been prompting you to do for some time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 1):

Either update to a newer ubuntu release, or you can do this :

```
sudo sed -i -re 's/([a-z]{2}\.)?archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

then :

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

thus your /etc/apt/sources.list should look like this :

> deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates main
>
> deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-backports main
>
> deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security main
>
> deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty main universe restricted multiverse

You should then be able to install the package.
If you are still having trouble then make sure you have the correct package name. Do a search on :

https://packages.ubuntu.com/